# Cannot set properties of undefined in Subscription callback

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have an observable which returns a value that I need to manipulate in a function, so I thought it would be cleaner if I just sent the function as a callback instead of creating a new anonymous function. However I made the change and I started getting this error message: `Error: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'name')`.

[STACKBLITZ DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rnwyza)

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
     this.updateName('First New Name!');

     of('Second New Name!')
     .pipe(delay(1500))
     // .subscribe(name => this.updateName(name)); // Works!
     .subscribe(this.updateName); // Doesn't work - Error: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'name')
  }

  updateName(name: string): void {
      this.name = name;
  }
```

Is it supposed to work this way? Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch `updateName` to lambda/arrow function.

```js
updateName = (name: string) => {
  this.name = name;
}
```

[Sample Demo on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w54bio?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

---

According to [Arrow function expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), arrow function doesn't own `this`.

> Arrow functions establish "this" based on the scope the Arrow function is defined within.

Hence, the arrow function works as

> `this` is looked up in scope just like a normal variable.

Credited from: [@Felix's answer on How to access the correct `this` inside a callback](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20279485/8017690)

Comment: It works, thank you! Could you please add some explanation or documentation about why is this behavior?